# Box shadow rendering incorrectly when element content expands and body has an image background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5boilerplate

I have a box shadow applied to a header div. Whenever I display the hidden elements within that header the box shadow doesn't render properly.

```
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"> 
    <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" /></a>
    <div id="navBtn"></div>
</div>
<div id="navlist"> <!-- hidden -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="coupons">Coupons</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="trans">Buy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried removing the background image from the body and when I do the issue no longer occurs. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RGLR3/5/)

Comment: Which browsers/versions have you tried?

Comment: It looks like the background image is trying to appear a second time behind the navigation items and on top of the original BG image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using [`background-attachment: scroll;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-attachment) - as it's value implies, the background scrolls with the content of the page (your header). You should instead use `fixed` so that the background-image is fixed with regard to the viewport.

Also note that `background-width` and `background-height` are not valid CSS properties, I believe you're instead looking for the [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-size) property.

http://jsfiddle.net/RGLR3/6/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in JSFiddle you're applying background to the body tag. That will not work as it will apply the background twice is jsfiddle which uses iframe to render your content - that is why it appears as if the box-shadow is messed up however it is not.

Try removing body tag and body css

instead you can have HTML like this:

```
<div class="outer-container">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"> <a href="<?=base_url(); ?>"><img src="http://pierdevara.com/demo/907pass/assets/img/907pass.png" /></a>

        <div id="navBtn"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="navlist">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="coupons">Coupons</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="trans">Buy / Activate</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the body css converted to :

```
.outer-container {
    background: url(http://pierdevara.com/demo/907pass/assets/img/bg_grassy.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-width: 2000px;
    background-height: 1300px;
    height:1300px;
}
```